# How does Automatak.DNP3.Interface.Ichannel work?

Tags: c#, dnp3

everybody. I am doing a project about C# and PLC. Currently I cannot understand how Automatak.DNP3.Interface.Ichannel works. Can anyone help me understand this clearly? Below is a picture containing something I don't understand. How will Ichannel get data?I see that such a declaration cannot be valid [image]